# programming an accounting software in visual basic

Tags: vb.net, vba

I want to learn programming accounting software in vb 6.0. Which book should I read for better achievement that teaches me everything step by step in advanced.

Comment: I would say it depends on your current knowledge of this (VB) or any other programming language. Where do you start off from? Beginner, Intermediate? Expert in ...?

Comment: I know Vb and accounting systems but don't know how to get started?

Answer (score 2):

I myself started off with Vb6 a few lightyears back.Golden old days. Over the past years though, like almost everyone else, we have moved to vb.net and now c#. 
If you are a beginner, sure you can still start with vb6, it is simple, easy to learn and then you can move on to more current technologies. However, in my opinion it will be better to start with either vb.net or c# directly. The reason being that most of the people are using these now, and lots of help is available. Whether you are looking for a job, or settingup your own company, vb.net ( and actually c# - they are verrrrry similar) would be a much better investment of time.

Rather than buying abook, you can also start with vb6 tutorials... see this link for absolute beginners
http://www.vb6.us/guides/visual-basic-6-beginners-guide

Wrox's books are pretty comprehensive, and yet beginner friendly. I'll provide you a link to the UK amazon for vb6 if you still want to go vb6 way, if you are not in the UK , you can search for it at a local bookstore/amazon

http://www.amazon.co.uk/Beginning-Visual-Basic-beginning-guides/dp/1861001053/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1364635699&sr=8-3

and as I said, why go vb6 way, when you will eventually end up using vb.net ( or c#). First get the free express edition of vb.net from microsoft here http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9816758
then this is a link to some great beginner tutorials for  vb.net. get coding!!!
http://howtostartprogramming.com/vb-net/

Comment: `programming accounting software in vb 6.0` ...... `I know Vb and`

Comment: You mean I could start using visual studio 2010? I have installed it on my pc.

Comment: ofcourse you can. It is , in my opinion better to learn that straightaway, rather than spending time learning it after spending all that time on vb6.

Comment: Could I get practical accounting system on the book?

Comment: what do you mean on the book?

Comment: no, what do you mean "On the book"? do you mean a copy of a complete software example written in vb on the book? perhaps. but you are better off downloading an opensource sample from codeplex.com . there are plenty of fully functional opensource software written in .net, and it is an excellent learning resource

Comment: I found there only software no source code.

Comment: I have come to know mainly only 3 tables are enough for accounting software that is accounts, batches and transactions. Could you please show me an example of table consisting Cash A/c Dr. 5000,  Ram A/c Dr. 3000 and John A/c Cr. 3000, Stackoverflow A/c Cr. 5000 with its relationships